# Plots not being shown in the colab

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

The plots are not being shown in the Colab when I am running a python file using iPython

Link to self-contained notebook that reproduces this issue: [Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OUu6NjrxpGUiytEk2bkzNRODxnnienh-)

Comment: Got the answer from respective team

https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1067#issuecomment-599771822

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, provided by the authors on a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1067#issuecomment-599771822):

> When you run
>
> ```
> !python scripy.py
> ```
>
> the script is executed in a sub-shell that is not connected to the
> notebook kernel, and so there is no way to have resulting charts
> display in the notebook.
>
> Instead you can use
>
> ```
> %run script.py
> ```
>
> to run your script within the current notebook session, and then plots
> will display inline.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60713572/3) to the question [Plots not being shown in the colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60713572/plots-not-being-shown-in-the-colab) by the OP [Mughees](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13073020/mughees) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>

Comment: Since it was posted by the OP, it should be a community wiki